# Blank page at beginning of of .pdf report generated in ColdFusion

Tags: adobe, coldfusion-8, cfpdf

I am generating a .pdf report from a ColdFusion program. The report is fine but I    always get an extra blank page at the beginning. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or missing?

```
<cfdocument format='pdf'>
<cfdocumentsection>  
<cfoutput>
```

Comment: What other code is involved in your PDF generation?

Comment: `cfdocumentsection` "..forces a page break so that each section starts on a new page". So depending on its placement, you could be creating a blank page unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

This is just me thinking out loud but you could create your PDF and store it to a temp location, then run a CFPDF function to trim the first page.

```
<cfpdf
 action = "deletepages"
 pages = "1"
 source = "/temp/#yourPDF#.pdf"
 overwrite = "yes"
destination = "pdfFolder/#yourPDF#.pdg">
```

Something like that?

UPDATE: Just noticed how old this question is. I think the real answer would be something like: Stop using ColdFusion. Either way, if anyone ever has this problem in the future I hope it helps.